# Is a yachid the congregation or the chazzan?

Tags: sukkot, minyan, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, hallel

When saying the Hallel on Sukkot one waves the 4 species at certain points. According to the Artscroll Machzor that I use, there are wavings that differ for the chazzan from what the kahal does (page 294). In the "hodu" section (Tehillim 118) the chazan waves when he says the first hodu line, and the yomar na yisrael line and that's it, while the congregation waves at each hodu.

When an individual davens without a minyan, does he assume the role of the chazzan and wave twice, or of the congregation and wave 4 times?

Comment: Option 3: he assumes neither and waves only for the first line.

Answer (score 2):

My Rov sent out a explanation for the davening on Hoshana Rabba as well as Simchas Torah which included what to do in the various sections of davening when not in a minyan.

> One who is davening alone without a minyan should only shake the Daled
> Minim for the 3 “Hodus” (one after “Halelu” and the 2 at the end of
> Hallel) and while reciting the first two “Ana Hashem’s.”
>
> One who is davening alone without a minyan should say all of the
> Hoshanos while holding the Daled Minim. There is no need to walk
> around anything.
>
> The Mishna Berurah says that one who is davening himself cannot say
> Mashiv Haruach until his tzibbur has already said it.